# Django - unable to build API

Tags: python, django, api, django-views, django-urls

Well, I'm trying to get to 'http:// 127.0.0.1:8000/api/files/", but getting a mistake, that:

```
Using the URLconf defined in WTF_2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
graphql/
Start/
The current path, api/file/, didn’t match any of these.
```

I understand what is this about, but can't really find where I did the mistake.
My 'File' model from 'Start/models.py:

```
class File(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish_date']

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
...
...
```

My 'urls.py' from 'Start/urls.py':

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import FileView

app_name = 'Start'
urlpatterns = [
    path('Start/', FileView.as_view()),
]
```

And my 'urls.py' from 'mainproject/urls.py':

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # graphiql = true указывает графену сделать доступным graphiql интерфейс
    path('graphql', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),
    # api интерфейс
    path('Start/', include('Start.urls'))
]
```

Comment: You put 'Start/' twice. So your path would be 'localhost:8000/Start/Start/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are calling the url `api/file` at some point however your urls.py file does not have that as a path.

You should consider adding the appropriate `api/file` url with the associated view to your `urls.py`.